# call_user_func with dynamic parameters

Tags: php, function, dynamic, parameters

I am using php 5.3 (Windows 7).

I create a function that call another function with dynamic variables

```
func A call func B.
func2($a, $b, $c, ) ... the number of parameters can be dynamic.
```

call_user_func("func2", $x) - what is the correct syntax to use : call_user function with parameters, that the number of parameters is unknown.

Thanks :)

Comment: see `func_get_args();` http://php.net/func_get_args . Also, you will need to use `call_user_func_array` instead of `call_user_func`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this http://www.php.net/call_user_func_array

```
    call_user_func_array('func2', array($a, $b, $c));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.
That's helped.

Comment: You can consider this issue as closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Best answer in years!